# UISearchBar's text field. right view not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uisearchbar

What i'm trying to implement is to move `UISearchBar`'s magnifier icon from the left edge of the text field to the right edge. This is how i do that:

```
    searchBar                   = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, FRSearchMaxHeight)];
    searchBar.delegate          = self;
    searchBar.placeholder       = NSLocalizedString(@"Search friends", "");
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    UIView *view = [searchBar subviewConformingToProtocol:@protocol(UITextInput)];

    UIView<UITextInput> *textInputView = (UIView<UITextInput> *)view;

    [textInputView setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
    [textInputView setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];

    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.9f green:0.9f blue:0.9f alpha:0.9f] size:searchBar.frame.size];
    [searchBar setBackgroundImage:image];

    textInputView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.f;
    textInputView.layer.borderWidth = 1.f;
    textInputView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;

    UIView *magnifier = [(UITextField *)textInputView leftView];
    [(UITextField *)textInputView setRightView:magnifier];
    [(UITextField *)textInputView setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeNever];
    [(UITextField *)textInputView setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

however the magnifier is never shown. It vanishes. I checked frame like this:

```
NSLog(@"FRAME %@", NSStringFromCGRect(((UITextField *)textInputView).rightView.frame));
```

and it says: `FRAME {{0, 0}, {12.5, 12.5}}`. What am i missing?

Comment: Is the UIView *magnifier being set? Could you please show it being logged?

Comment: @InfinityJames i'm not sure if i got you right, but i think you're asking does it even exist when i refer to it. the answer is yes

Comment: @InfinityJames and this is its description <UIImageView: 0xb430fb0; frame = (0 0; 12.5 12.5); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb4306c0>>

Comment: What happens if you do everything the same, but replace the magnifier in `[(UITextField *)textInputView setRightView:magnifier]; ` with a UIView with the same frame, and just a backgroundColor to make it easy to spot? Just to see if adding a rightView works in another scenario.

Comment: @InfinityJames nothing happens. can't set any rightView on iOS7. i can set left, but not right. and only on ios7. funny, isn't it?